# What does the ALTER ... LOGFILE command do in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm studying some SQL code that a colleague gave me, and it has some commands for manipulating REDO logs, changing memory , etc.

What does the following command do ?

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=[/LOCATION]' SCOPE=both;



ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;  /* simulate a bunch of log switches*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log_archive_dest_n` defines the options for archiving online redo logs when using Oracle Data Guard, see
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/log_arch_dest_param.htm#SBYDB01101.

`ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;` switches online redo log to the next file in the group. This effectively leads to archival of current log file. See
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/onlineredo.htm#ADMIN11308